# HTML entitys: When to encode and when not to?

Tags: html-entities

Whenever I create an html page I have to replace all the special characters with html entities such as `&amp;` or `&quot;` 
if I view the source of any of my pages I can see these enities as I wrote them.

Why is it then that whenever I view other peoples websites the source contains the unencoded special characters? It feels to me like I'm missing something but I just can't see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out by accident. It is because the page was encoded as ANSI instead of UTF-8 without BOM